# How to download and INSTALL apps in the memory card? (and not the phone memory)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung, insufficient-memory

How to download and INSTALL apps in the SD memory card? (and not the phone memory known as Device Storage)

Since when I download something on Aptoide it says that my memory is full. The fact is, my device storage memory is full but my SD memory card is empty.

I have an Android based Samsung Galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

check out this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ljmobile.move.app
may be it can be helpful. There is a bit work but it get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be completely up to date on this but there may be no solution to this, as (most?) android apps cannot installed on the sd card, some of their data can be moved (resources and such) if the developer prepared for that.

So a solution to your memory problem may be to attempt to move some of the app data to the sd card (if you run into issues to this, let me know your version of android and I will try to help).

Answer (score 0):

My mobile(Android 2.3) **has in-built option** for that:

```
Settings>Applications>Manage Applications
```

then Select app and click "Move to Phone".

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was in 2013 that Google supposedly instructed apps writers to discontinue allowing apps to be installed to SD cards.  Something about apps not working any longer after an SD card is removed, then re-installed.  I discovered that after purchasing a 16GB Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 with a 64 Gigabyte microSD card.  I currently have 4Gigabyte available of the 16 original in the system available for use.  Though I can't put apps on the card, I put the card in a laptop
 PC and transferred videos mpg4, photos, songs and documents on the card then reinsert ed the card into the Samsung.  It works fine.  There are a few apps that may still able to be installed on the card, but still won't work if the card is removed then reinstalled.

Answer (score -1):

Please visit this link :

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1278349

The post is to help you set your phones default install path to your phones sd card on any android device.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

1. free some space on device (by uninstalling unnecessary apps) to download desired app
2. move downloaded app to sd-card so that it will require less space on device
3. you can use Link2sd app to move app forcefully (root require)